# find a special node with its attribute from a XmlNodeList

Tags: c#, .net, xml, winforms, xmlnode

I have an `XmlNodeList` that would like to find a special node inside it.
I used the following code but I it does not find the desired node spite of it is in the `XmlNodeList`.

```
string ID = "9";
public void XMlNodeFind(XmlNodeList steps, string ID)
{
    var resultNodes = new List<XmlNode>();
    foreach (XmlNode node in steps)
    {
        if (node.Attributes["name"].Value.Equals(ID))
        {
            resultNodes.Add(node);
        }
    }
}
```

and here is XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<files>
    <file name="1">
        <file name="3">
            <file name="9">
            </file> 
        </file> 
    </file>
    <file name="2">
        <text here are some text/>
    </file>
</files>
```

Comment: And how did you populate the `XmlNodeList` initially?

Comment: ``XmlNodeList steps = root1.SelectNodes("//files/file");``

Comment: Also, `resultNodes` is not returned by `XMlNodeFind()`, so how did you check the result?

Comment: I know it had no return. But `resultNodes` is `null` till end of `foreach`.

Comment: As an aside, are you able to use LINQ to XML instead of XmlDocument etc? It generally makes things like this trivial.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yap, I can use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've said you can use LINQ to XML, I'd use something like this:

```
public List<XElement> FindElementsByName(XDocument doc, string name)
{
    return doc.Descendants()
              .Where(x => (string) x.Attribute("name") == name)
              .ToList();
}
```

(In C# 6 you could use an expression-bodied method, of course.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would you please add `()` to the `doc.Descendants`.

Comment: @SaberJalilzadeh: Done.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `//files/file` only returns `file` elements that is *direct child* of `files`. If you want to get all `file` elements no matter how deep it is nested within `files` you should use `//` instead :

```
XmlNodeList steps = root1.SelectNodes("/files//file");
```

Currently your function compares `XmlAttribute` against string which will always evaluates to `false`. So, as mentioned in the other answer, you should've compared the value instead. Also, the entire function can be simplified with the help of LINQ :

```
public void XMlNodeFind(XmlNodeList steps, string ID)
{
    var resultNodes = steps.Cast<XmlNode>()
                           .Where(o => o.Attributes["name"].Value.Equals(ID))
                           .ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a `recursive` function to traverse through all the nodes and find matching nodes.

```
public  List<XmlNode> XMlNodeFind(XmlNodeList steps, string ID)
{
    var resultNodes = new List<XmlNode>();
    foreach (XmlNode node in steps)
    {
        if (node.Attributes != null && node.Attributes["name"] != null &&node.Attributes["name"].Value.Equals(ID))
        {
            resultNodes.Add(node);
        }
        resultNodes.AddRange(XMlNodeFind(node.ChildNodes, ID));

    }
    return resultNodes;
}
```

Comment: You need the `.Value`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this, but I would suggest to use LINQ to XML if you are allowed to:

```
string ID = "9";

public void XMlNodeFind(XmlNodeList steps, string ID)
{
    var resultNodes = new List<XmlNode>();
    foreach (XmlNode node in steps)
    {
        if (node.Attributes["name"].Value.Equals(ID))
        {
            resultNodes.Add(node);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:1**

Firstly the information you provided is incorrect. you don't have the specific node in `steps` even though it is present in the xml.

You need `SelectNodes("/files//file");` to get it into the list.

Thats all I guess, works fine for me.

Comment: When you edit your question with some fix, please comment it as a edit. Makes us look like fools.

Comment: It was a typo, sorry